# Center div in a footer

Tags: html, css

I want to align a list of links in the footer of my website, but no matter what I try, it doesn't seem to align in the center of the footer (Like in the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) footer for example).

I have tried using `display: block`, `display: inline-block`, `text-align: center` and others but no matter what I do I can never seem to get it right.

CSS:

```
footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  }

footer div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  }

footer {
  margin-left: 25%;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<footer>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Vine</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">YouTube</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Twitch</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Mobcrush</a>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">SoundCloud</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">GitHub</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Pastebin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Curse</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">~</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">~</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">~</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">~</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide us jsfiddle.net .?

Comment: if you want something just like w3schools you'll have to use a css grid like skeletonCSS

Comment: `footer { text-align: center; }`

Comment: @hemnathmouli https://jsfiddle.net/ItzJavaCraft/Lpne4psw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `display:flex;` on the footer.

```css
footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  }

footer div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  }

footer {
  display:flex;
  
  }
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Vine</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">YouTube</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Twitch</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Mobcrush</a>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">SoundCloud</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">GitHub</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Pastebin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Curse</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">~</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">~</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">~</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="_blank">~</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
footer {text-align: center;}
footer div { display: inline-block; }
```

Is that you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Try Display Table

```
footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  }

footer div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  }

footer {
  margin-left: 25%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width of your footer element to 50% (25% left margin + 50% width leaves an effective 25% right margin, thus centering the footer itself first) and set the text-align of the footer element to center, it will center the footer divs how you want.  Note, however, that this sets the text-alignment of the child elements to center as well, but in this case that appears to be what you want.

```
footer {
  margin-left: 25%;
  width:50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```